# Copying 2-D Python List into Excel WorkSheet

Tags: python, vba, excel, win32com

I have a 2D python List of arbitrary length. I would like to copy this list into an excel worksheet using win32com.

```
mylist = [["A1","B1","C1","D1"],["A2","B2"],["A3","B3","C3"]]
import win32com.client
from win32com.client import constants as c
excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
wb = excel.Workbooks.Add()
ws = wb.Worksheets.Add()
```

At this point is there something I could do to accomplish my task?

Comment: You'll need to loop through the top-level array and then through each of the sub-arrays. Use a row and column counter to assign each value to the appropriate cell.

Comment: This might be helpful: http://pythonexcels.com/python-excel-mini-cookbook/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the standard [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module to create a CSV file, which you can then open in Excel.

Comment: +1: I second this. It's easy enough to use the `CSV` writer for this job. Unless OP wants a specific reason to go via Excel on the get-go, this is the best way to do it.